# I want to change the default logo size of 400 to 1100 width. how to do that?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change my header logo size from 400 to 1100 width but i don't know where to put the size. What code should i put? Thank you

`

```
        $nicdark_customizer_logo_img = get_option( 'nicdark_customizer_logo_img' );
        if ( $nicdark_customizer_logo_img == '' or $nicdark_customizer_logo_img == 0 ) { ?>

        <div class="nicdark_grid_3 nicdark_text_align_center_responsive">
            <div class="nicdark_section nicdark_height_10"></div>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>"><h3 class="nicdark_color_white"><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo( 'name' )); ?></h3></a>
            <div class="nicdark_section nicdark_height_10"></div>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>"><p class="nicdark_font_size_13"><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo( 'description' )); ?></p></a>
            <div class="nicdark_section nicdark_height_10"></div>
        </div>

    <?php

        }else{ 

            $nicdark_customizer_logo_img = wp_get_attachment_url($nicdark_customizer_logo_img);

        ?>

        <div class="nicdark_grid_3 nicdark_text_align_center_responsive">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>">
                <img class="nicdark_section" src="<?php echo esc_url($nicdark_customizer_logo_img); ?>">
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
    <!--END LOGO OR TAGLINE--> `
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Go to WordPress Admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS.

**Step 2:** Add below mentioned code in additional CSS to change the size of the logo. You just need to change max height and max width as per your need.

Comment: Select top header Background, for more customization use the ID "nd_options_navigation_4_top_header" and add your custom css rules on Customizer -> Additional CSS 

My header option says like this

Comment: Hello please reply

Comment: i think it's helpfull url please check it, https://wpsmackdown.com/wordpress-site-logo-customizer/